# Rule 14.2 A for loop shall be well-formed for MISRA C 2012

Tags: c, for-loop, misra

Why my tool for analysis of the rule for MISRA report a possible violation for this for loop ? 
For example

```
for(; i != 0 ; i = f(r) ) { int a = 9 + i; }
```

Comment: Maybe a side effect with `f(r)`. Try to put it into the loop body.

Comment: And what about a start condition for `i`?

Comment: Might want to consider using a while loop instead, if the purpose of the loop is to repeatedly check/use the result of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to MISRA C 2012 document, the third clause of a `for` statement shall be an expression whose only persistent side effect is to modify the value of the loop counter and it shall not use objects that are modified in the `for` loop body. These restrictions also apply to all functions called within `for` statement.

From the code you provided, I can guess, that `f(r)` function call contains side effects, such as modification of global variables or `r` argument. All other requirement described in rule 14.2 text are met.